# how to create new view(screen) on play 2.5.x

Tags: java, playframework

It's failed to create new view on play framework 2.5.x.

Default sample view page can be showed from standard package.

please let me know what's the cause?

- situation*

・Error details:
refer to below comment "// ← " part

・Things I did as follows:

1)
[controllers > test.java]

```
package controllers;
import play.mvc.Controller;
import play.mvc.Result;
import views.html.login;       // ← "login" is resolved error
public class testClass extends Controller {
     public static Result showTop() {
        return ok(login.render());   // ← "login" is resolved error
    }
}
```

2)
[views > login.scala.html]

!DOCTYPE html
html
something...

3)
[conf > routes]
GET     /login                        controllers.testClass.showTop()

Comment: You did not define `login`. Where did you create it ?

Comment: How should it be created?
I didn't still know much about using play FW.

Comment: This is Object Oriented Programming, Objects are created like this `T variable = new T()`. Where did you create the instance `login`? Also, who calls `showTop()` ?

Comment: I didn't create Instance.
showTop() should be called from "GET ..." from routes.
I expect to create instance when access /login URL.

It's compiled error now.

I referred to sample package code (index)

Comment: Would it be possible to teach how standard package system works up to display welcome page.

Comment: @UDKOX  , According to an older Play framework documentation I found, import views.html.login is correct as that login class is generated when login.scala.html is compiled.

However, I too am getting an error as it is saying login does not exist.

This leads me to believe new scala.html template files are not being compiled, but I am unsure how to make sure all my template files are being targeted (not just the default main and index ones)